# Grub 2.0.2: Cannot boot to Windows 10 (dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

Today, when turn on computer and chooise boot to Windows 10, I got this error: `"relocation failed"`
[image]

[image]

The last time I use computer is Ubuntu 18.04 and I make some update with `"apt update && apt dist-upgrade"`

I also make update graphic driver, but I don't think it make problem: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`

I had tried some fix methods in Ubuntu but no luck:

- Update grub: `sudo update-grub2`
- Install and run boot-repair: `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

The content of Windows boot entry:

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  68FC-75FB
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 68FC-75FB
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

Disk partations:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fix this problem, not solve the root cause but it work:
In BIOS, these is have two special boot option as image below:
[image]

- Windows Boot Manager
- Ubuntu

So I try the option `Windows Boot Manager`, computer boot to the same boot menu entries as post above, but this time booting to Windows is success.

I don't why but this option fix my problem, so I make it default in BIOS.
[image]

Comment: This is wrong and may confuse other users. What you should have done is select Ubuntu as the primary bootloader, boot Ubuntu and then `sudo update-grub` (not the command you used, not Boot Repair)

Comment: I tested with command `sudo update-grub` but no success

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation.

I my case in the bios was 2 entry with "ubuntu", and the order was:

uefi (ubuntu), uefi (windows), uefi (ubuntu)....

swapping "ubuntu" entries resolve the problem.

probably the "ubuntu" boot entries are not the same and have different options.